# "File too large" when merging a video file on TubeMate

Tags: external-sd, video, downloading, youtube, tubemate

I have Samsung Galaxy Note 2 and I'm using TubeMate 2.1.2 to download an HD video on YouTube. After the download finished, there is a merging file problem, and an error appeared:

> File too large

However, I have a huge empty space on my SD card.

What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: This question is completely unique to "tubemate" as an application and should be filed as a bug with the developers of that application.

Comment: any suggestions for another app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TubeMate app might be using phone's internal storage for merging.

Comment: I change default download to my SD card and vid size is 5 GB while my external storage is 11 GB

Comment: according to me tubemate uses phone internal storage for temporary storing of video for merging so you are out of luck.however you can mail to tubemate team concerning your problem.

Comment: from tubemate guide ,,,                                How to save videos to SD external card?
TubeMate automatically save videos to /mnt/sdcard/Video folder. Almost all devices have this folder in SD external card. However, Samsung Galaxy series have this folder in phone device internal drive. So if you want to save videos to SD card, please go to preferences and change your download folder as '/mnt/sdcard/external_sd' or '/mnt/sdcard/sd' or any folder in SD external card.
If you don't know how to change the saving folder, please look at http://m.tubemate.net/help/change_folder.jsp.

Comment: Consider verifying 3osman's last comment and adding it into your answer.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using default location of internal storage, then it needs more time to clear buffers and sometime have memory problem. So it's better to change the video download location to `sdcard` which should be large capacity as compared to file.

Comment: Why would storage location affect the buffer? Do you have _anything_ to support this?